# How to set Razor Component EventCallback from Razor Page

Tags: razor-pages, razor-components

I want to set the EventCallback parameter of a Razor Component from a Razor Page.

I have create a test Razor Component and want to raise an EventCallback back to the parent which is a Razor Page. The component itself is working, but it looks like the EventCallback is not getting set.

This is the code of the component

```
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    [Parameter]
    public int InitialValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> OnClick { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Action OnClickNew { get; set; }


    private void IncrementCount() {

        currentCount++;

        OnClick.InvokeAsync(currentCount);
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        currentCount = InitialValue;
    }
}
```

And below is the Razor Page snippet

```
<component type="typeof(RazorTest.Components.Test)" param-InitialValue="0" OnClick="test" render-mode="Server" />

@{
    void test(int count = 0)
    {
        var t = "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

InvokeAsync is asynchronous. You need

```
private async Task IncrementCount() {
    currentCount++;
    await OnClick.InvokeAsync(currentCount);
}
```